# iPhone: UIBarButtonSystemItemSave and Localization

Tags: iphone, localization

I'm using the UIBarButtonSystemItemSave to get a Save button in my iPhone app. My idea was that using these system items, I should get automatic localization for these buttons. But it still says "Save" in all languages. Isn't they automatically translated? Do I need to do it myself?

My Code:

```
UIBarButtonItem* saveItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave 
    target:self action:@selector(saveButtonClicked:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveItem;
[saveItem release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange... In my app it translates autoatically.

Comment: For some reason my simulator hadn't reload, must have been cache. I deleted the app and Clean and rebuild, and now it is working.